# Find out if process / file is running linux

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I want to check if a process is running or not. I've been trying by

```
ps -C /path/file
```

and get this response:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

If I do

```
pgrep php
```

I get a list of php processes running, but only the PID.

Is there a possibility to

- determine the PID of a file I specify (I want to type the file and get the PID)
- get the filename if I type the PID
- get all the running processes PIDs in a file to work with that in a later script

*OS:* *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*

I've been looking for this since quite some time, tried all the possibilities I found on SO and else but just can't figure out how to do this best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Determine the PID of a file I specify."

```
lsof | grep <file> | awk '{print $2}'
```

"Get the filename if I type the PID."

```
lsof | grep <PID>
lsof | grep <PID> | awk '{print $NF}'
```

"Get all the running processes PIDs in a file to work with that in a later script."

```
ps x | awk '{print $1}' > pid-list.txt # PIDs of all processes run by current user
ps ax | awk '{print $1}' > pid-list.txt # PIDs of all processes run by all users
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `ps aux | grep <the-name-of-the-process>`.

Comment: Maybe I was to hasty, or does this answer your question at all?

Comment: The part with the determining PID in any case! Thank you! Do you know a possibility to safe all running PIDs in a file?

Comment: Not sure about that part.. sorry. Please consider accepting the answer if you feel satisfied :)

Comment: So what you ask for is basically to have all PID's for one type of process in the same file?